# How can I do this math formula in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I need to work out what is the volume of liquid left in a cylinder on its side in JavaScript, how will I do the following in code?

[image]

Comment: tell us what you tried and show some expected input and output. Also image is not a great idea for what you want to show here

Comment: Please edit the code and add what you have done

Comment: Hi Currently i'm doing it all on percentage which is wrong,

    var TotL =  112; // Total Tank Diameter in cm
    var TotLL = 2200; //Total Tank in Liters
    
    var LLeft1 = 0;

    
    L1 = 72 // depth cm
    
    L1 = TotL - L1;
    LLeft1 = (L1/TotL)*100;
    LLeft1 = 100/LLeft1;
    LLeft1 = TotLL/LLeft1;
    LLeft1 = LLeft1.toFixed(2); // Amount left in tank in Liter = 785.71L

Comment: Show us the code you currently have. Also, in the formula, what's `R`? And `D`? Be more precise.

Comment: I cant edit the question to to the code nicely,

i added to a jsfidde

https://jsfiddle.net/yqot3gxm/

R  is the radius of the cylinder.
D  is the depth.
L   is the length of the cylinder

Comment: This is more about how to convert the math formula into JavaScript Math library functions.  There are a number of Math functions you can  use to perform the operations needed. It just comes down to order of operations. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: Thanks Matt will check through the formulas, my brain is exploding. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.I have used [Math.acos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/acos) and [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).And rest is simple Mathematics.

> Since Math.acos returns NaN if the number is not between (-1 and 1)
>   ,so I have checked before if the acos returns NaN

```js
function volume(diameter, depth, length) {
  let R = diameter / 2;

  if (Math.acos((R - depth )/ R) != NaN) {
    let a = Math.pow(R, 2) * Math.acos((R - depth) / R) - (R - depth) * (Math.pow((2 * R * depth - Math.pow(depth, 2)), 0.5))

return a * length;
 } else {
return "Cylinder radius can't be less than depth"

  }
}
// returns volume in meter cube
// 1 meter cube =1000l
console.log(volume(1.08, 0.72, 2.40)*1000,"L")
```

Comment: Shubh thanks for the function putting me on the right path, when i run the  code i get 1.9604834872505212L but must be 1557.0761, will be tweaking the function to get the value, but major THANKS Shubh, who says hero's were capes ;)

Comment: Please check the updated answer @QLion ,it is outputting the exact value.Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- `**` operator for powers (or `Math.pow`)
- `Math.acos` for `cos^(-1)`
- `Math.sqrt` for the square root

```js
console.log(calculateVolumeInCylinder(1.08, 2.4, 0.72))

/**
 * @param {number} Dm - Cylinder diameter in meters.
 * @param {number} L - Cylinder length in meters.
 * @param {number} Dp - Depth in meters.
 * @returns {number} Volume in liters.
 */
function calculateVolumeInCylinder(Dm, L, Dp) {
  let R = Dm / 2,
    // R^2 cos^-1(R-D/R)
    sA = R ** 2 * Math.acos((R - Dp) / R),
    // (R-D)
    sB = (R - Dp),
    // SQRT(2RD-D^2)
    sC = Math.sqrt(2 * R * Dp - Dp ** 2);
    
  return (L * (sA - sB * sC)) * 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Shubh and Matt Major Thanks!!!! i manage to do it via the following.

```js
function round(d)
// Returns a number rounded to 4 decimal places.
{ var multiplier = 10000;
  return Math.round(d*multiplier) / multiplier;
};


function negative(n)
{ if(n<0)
     complain("Negative input");
  return (n<0);
}

function calculate(vdiam,vlen,vdepth){ 

  //var vdiam  = 1.08;
  //var vlen   = 2.40;
  //var vdepth = 0.72;
  var res = 0;  //result


  //Convert inputs to numbers
  d = new Number(vdiam);
  l = new Number(vlen);
  h = new Number(vdepth);
  r = d/2;

  if(negative(d)) return;
  if(negative(l)) return;
  if(negative(h)) return;

  //make sure it's all kosher
  if(h>d)
 { console.log("Depth exceeds diameter");
      return;
    }



  //calculate
  var segArea =r*r*Math.acos((r-h)/r) - (r-h)*Math.sqrt(2*r*h-h*h);
  res = segArea*l;
  if(isNaN(res))
 { console.log("Inputs must be positive numbers");
   res = "";
      return;
 }

 res = res*1000;
  
  return round(res);

}


alert(calculate(1.08,2.40,0.72));
```